# remove siblings class from a href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using owl carousel on a menu. 
when I scroll to the div the owl carousel auto slide to the right slides. 
now when I arrived in the specific div I add class to the slide (active) but for some reason, I can't remove the active class from the other slides (his siblings).

I think it will be best to check the jsfiddle to understand the problem...

```
<div class="body">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
      <a href="#a" data-num="0">Review</a>
      <a href="#a" data-num="1" class="item">a</a>
      <a href="#b" data-num="2" class="item">b</a>
      <a href="#c" data-num="3" class="item">c</a>
      <a href="#d" data-num="4" class="item">d</a>
      <a href="#d" data-num="5" class="item">e</a>
      <a href="#d" data-num="6" class="item">f</a>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

JS file

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    nav: false,
    dots: false,
    singleItem: true,
})
   var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
   owl.owlCarousel();

   $( window ).scroll(function() {
      let scrollbarLocation = $(this).scrollTop();

        let scrollLinks = $('.item');

        scrollLinks.each(function(){
            let sectionOffset = $(this.hash).offset().top;

            if (sectionOffset <= scrollbarLocation){
                $(this).siblings().removeClass('active-link');
                $(this).addClass('active-link');

                let goToSlide = $(this).attr('data-num')
                owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', goToSlide);
            }
        })

        if( scrollbarLocation === 0){
            scrollLinks.removeClass('active-link');
            owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', 0);
        }
    });
```

check https://jsfiddle.net/jt31h4pr/132/

Comment: wait. You add class `active-link` . the class `active` is added by the carousel. Which one you want to control ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/09sLpuwd/1/

What are you doing wrong is trying to remove active class from `this` and then add active class to the same `this`, which actualy do nothing.
Insted what I propose is to remove active class from all `'.item'` emelements and than add it to active one.

As alternative aproach you can store previous item and remove class from it, but I think first way is better.

Comment: You are welcome. But I think Mihai T version is more efficient, since it is obvious that it will be faster to do $('.active-link').removeClass('active-link'); than $('.item').removeClass('active-link'); becouse first one will always contain only one element.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you remove/add `active-link` class on the same element ( this ). You need to removeClass only on the the element that already has class `active-link`.
The class `active` is controlled by the plugin and all the elements that are visible have the `active` class

See below

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    nav: false,
    dots: false,
    singleItem: true,
})
    var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
  owl.owlCarousel();
    
   $( window ).scroll(function() {
      let scrollbarLocation = $(this).scrollTop();
      
        let scrollLinks = $('.item');
    
        scrollLinks.each(function(){
          
            let sectionOffset = $(this.hash).offset().top;
            if (sectionOffset <= scrollbarLocation){
             $('.active-link').removeClass('active-link'); // added
              
              $(this).addClass('active-link');
             
              
                let goToSlide = $(this).attr('data-num')
                owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', goToSlide);
            }
        })
    
        if( scrollbarLocation === 0){
            scrollLinks.removeClass('active-link');
            owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', 0);
        }
    });
```

```css
.body {
  height: 5000px;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 15px;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
}

.active-link {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #000;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background: #f8f9fb;
}

#a {
  background: lightblue;
  margin-top: 200px;
}
#b {
  background: lightgreen;
}
#c {
  background: tomato;
}
#d {
  background: lightpink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.css">


<div class="body">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
      <a href="#a" data-num="0">Review</a>
      <a href="#a" data-num="1" class="item">a</a>
      <a href="#b" data-num="2" class="item">b</a>
      <a href="#c" data-num="3" class="item">c</a>
      <a href="#d" data-num="4" class="item">d</a>
      <a href="#d" data-num="5" class="item">e</a>
      <a href="#d" data-num="6" class="item">f</a>
    </ul>
  </div>



<section id="a"></section>
<section id="b"></section>
<section id="c"></section>
<section id="d"></section>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi the problem is with below line

```
$(this).siblings().removeClass('active-link');
```

replace it with

```
$("div.active a").removeClass('active-link');
```

This was removing and adding class on same time on all so what i did is once i am removing the class from all i am adding it on present elemnt